# Navigate 2 screens back when a user clicks on Android's back button? (Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

How do I get the app to navigate 2 screens back when a user clicks on Android's back button?

Code below:

```
if(document.getElementById("HomeCtrl") != undefined){
        navigator.notification.confirm(messages[appLanguage].exitFromApp, function(buttonIndex){
            if(buttonIndex == 1){
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            };
        }, messages[appLanguage].appName, ["Ok","Cancel"])
        this.preventDefault();
    } else if(document.getElementById("BookCabController") != undefined){
        angular.element(document.getElementById("BookCabController")).scope().navigationService.back();
    } else if(document.getElementById("ReviewAndConfirmController") != undefined){
        angular.element(document.getElementById("ReviewAndConfirmController")).scope().navigationService.back();            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine for you.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false );
}

function onBackKeyDown() {
    history.go(-2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion,  but Its not working for a specific controller , would you please suggest any other idea?

Comment: What do you mean with specific controller? What does happen with that code? Errors? Nothing? What exactly? I suggest you as many other ideas as i can till we solve your problem ;).

Comment: I have edited the question with my current code snippet, Instead of back once we would like to back twice (so that previous of previous screen) or to land on a specific screen.